# bs4 get contents after different tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am getting programmatically the following html output:

```
htmls = """\
'<p><strong>test</strong></p><p><strong>test</strong></p><p><strong>MULTIPLE CHOICE</strong></p><p>\t1.\tThis is first mcq</p><table><tr><td><p>a.</p></td><td><p>o1</p></td></tr><tr><td><p>b.</p></td><td><p>o2</p></td></tr><tr><td><p>c.</p></td><td><p>o3</p></td></tr><tr><td><p>d.</p></td><td><p>o4</p></td></tr><tr><td><p>e.</p></td><td><p>o5</p></td></tr></table><p>ANS:\tA\tPTS:\t1\tDIF:\tEasy\tTOP:\ttopi</p><p>\t2.\tThis is second mcq</p><table><tr><td><p>a.</p></td><td><p>o1</p></td></tr><tr><td><p>b.</p></td><td><p>o2</p></td></tr><tr><td><p>c.</p></td><td><p>o3</p></td></tr><tr><td><p>d.</p></td><td><p>o4</p></td></tr><tr><td><p>e.</p></td><td><p>o5</p></td></tr></table><p>ANS:\tC\tPTS:\t1\tDIF:\tEasy\tTOP:\ttopi</p><p>\t3.\tThis is third mcq</p><table><tr><td><p>a.</p></td><td><p>o1</p></td></tr><tr><td><p>b.</p></td><td><p>o2</p></td></tr><tr><td><p>c.</p></td><td><p>o3</p></td></tr><tr><td><p>d.</p></td><td><p>o4</p></td></tr><tr><td><p>e.</p></td><td><p>o5</p></td></tr></table><p>ANS:\tE\tPTS:\t1\tDIF:\tEasy\tTOP:\ttopic</p><p><strong>MATCHING</strong></p> <p>matching</p><table><tr><td><p>a.</p></td><td><p>a1</p></td><td><p>e.</p></td><td><p>a5</p></td></tr><tr><td><p>b.</p></td><td><p>a2</p></td><td><p>f.</p></td><td><p>a6</p></td></tr><tr><td><p>c.</p></td><td><p>a3</p></td><td><p>g.</p></td><td><p>a7</p></td></tr><tr><td><p>d.</p></td><td><p>a4</p></td></tr></table><p>\t1.\tq1</p><p>\t2.\tq2</p><p>\t3.\tq3</p><p>\t4.\tq4</p><p>\t5.\tq5</p><p>\t1.\tANS:\tA\tPTS:\t1</p><p>\t2.\tANS:\tB\tPTS:\t1</p><p>\t3.\tANS:\tC\tPTS:\t1</p><p>\t4.\tANS:\tD\tPTS:\t1</p><p>\t5.\tANS:\tE\tPTS:\t1</p><p><strong>ESSAY</strong></p> <p>\t1.\tThis is first SAQ</p><p>ANS:\t</p><p>SAQ first ANSKEY</p><p>PTS:\t1\tTOP:\tTOPIC</p><p>\t2.\tThis is second SAQ</p><p>ANS:\t</p><p>SAQ second ANSKEY</p><p>PTS:\t1\tTOP:\tTOPIC</p><p>\t3.\tThis is third SAQ</p><p>ANS:\t</p><p>SAQ is ANSKEY</p><p>PTS:\t1\tTOP:\tTOPIC</p>'"""
```

Owing to dynamic nature of the contents there will be texts with  tags with different contents. The number of occurrences of these tags is not consistent. I want to get texts after these tags, I want to extract text immediately after these tags, ie:

```
MCQ=<p>cla cla</p>
MATCH=dla dla 
ESSAY= ela ela
```

All my attempts such as below returns None:

```
import bs4 as bs
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(htmls,'lxml')
MCQ = soup.find('strong',text='MCQ').next_sibling
MCQ = soup.find('strong',text='MCQ').next_string
```

What I need is color coded in the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `.find_next_sibling()` with `text=True`:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_doc = """\
<strong>test</strong> ala ala 
<strong>test</strong> bla bla
<strong>MCQ</strong>cla cla 
<strong>MATCH</strong> dla dla 
<strong>ESSAY</strong>ela ela"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "lxml")

MCQ = soup.find("strong", text="MCQ").find_next_sibling(text=True).strip()
print(MCQ)
```

Prints:

```
cla cla
```

Comment: When there are tags after that it throws None. Please see updated inputs

Comment: @Shiva With updated input you do `MCQ = soup.find("strong", text="MCQ").next_sibling.text.strip()`

Comment: Thanks again. I m getting now: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: @Shiva Try to do `print(soup)` and check that the sibling tag is really there.

Comment: Thanks again, I checked with printing soup and there are text with tags  existing  `<html><body><p><strong>test</strong></p><p><strong>test</strong></p><p><strong>MULTIPLE CHOICE</strong></p><p> 1. This is first mcq</p><table><tr><td><p>a.</p></td><td><p>o1</p></td></tr><tr><td><p>b.</p></td><td><p>o2</p></td></tr><tr><td><p>c.</p>`

Comment: @Shiva And what information you want from get from this HTML?

Comment: Thanks again for patiently helping me. Please see the figure I need each colour coded strings are to be returned